# Auto-submitting form of ajax element

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to auto-submit form that has been loaded via ajax with jquery?

Scenario:
1) Some kind of form is submitted on page.
2) That form(step1) loads another form via ajax
3) Loaded form via ajax(step2) is auto-submitted

So i guess what i'm looking for is some kind of `.live();` replacemenet or something since i don't have any event to bind it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? Barebones example:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#someDiv").load(this.action, function () {
        $(this).find("form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Great guess i was looking for `this.action` part. Thanks